# How to get ABI name in Gradle outputs iterator

Tags: android, gradle

I'm composing `.apk` filename using current app version and flavor name. I'd like to add current ABI split name as well, but only if it's a universal apk.

My relevant `build.gradle` sections:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def flavor = ....  // some code to parse flavor & determine an appropriate string from it
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "app_" + flavor + "_0" + variant.versionCode + ".apk")
            }
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
    deploy {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'armeabi-v7a' //select ABIs to build APKs for
                universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this config generates two .apks, but they both have the same file name as I don't know how to get the ABI name, so the one generated later overwrites the one generated before.

So, what is the equivalent `variant.productFlavors.get(0)` for current ABI split?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's very strange as flavor and ABI-name is automatically added to build name (if you make corresponding assemble)

can you try completely remove your custom made naming

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def flavor = ....  // some code to parse flavor & determine an appropriate string from it
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "app_" + flavor + "_0" + variant.versionCode + ".apk")
            }
        }
```

and instead of that try to add to defaultConfig this line

```
 archivesBaseName = "app_${versionCode}"
```

If this is will not resolve you issues you can try to get abi from output

```
output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
```

Comment: > output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI) < It works for me, thanx!

Comment: Is it same for gradle 3.x plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent is `output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)`.

Note that, starting with Android Studio 3.0, you should use `outputFileName` and `variant.outputs.all` instead:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = "app_" + output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI) + "_0" + variant.versionCode + ".apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: `com.android.build.OutputFile` is deprecated now

Comment: Any alternative for `com.android.build.OutputFile` or another way to get the ABI name of the output?

Comment: You can simply use `"ABI"` (string) instead of `OutputFile.ABI`.